# Android sleep without thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep

How can i make code sleep without threading / runnable. I require to modify layout in a android app, operate a method and reverse layout changes again. However this methods contains counters, whenever i have a inner class, like a runnable timertask or something simular the variable needs to be final, but then i cannot increase the counters.

```
ChangeLayout();

int round = 0;
while (isPlaying && round < 24){
    round++;
    int specificOccurrence = 0;
    while (isPlaying && specificOccurence < 8) {
        if (somethingSpecific){
            specificOccurence++;
        }
        // operates this while somehow with a 1 second break;
        // after that just continue.
        waitASecondSomehow();
    }
}

ReverseLayoutChanges();
```

Comment: put this code in different thread...you are executing whole code in main thread

Comment: Just post a `Runnable` with a one second delay.

Comment: that way i cannot `mistakes++;` because its requires to be final, which i dont require because i need to modify it.

Comment: how about adding a `synchronized void incrementMistakes()` method that will do that for you? You should be able to call it from a different thread then, provided that `mistakes` is `volatile`

Comment: Also, instead of calling `sleep()` use a `Handler` and `postDelayed(thisRunnable, 1000)` to schedule another call one second from now.

Comment: can you give an example/dummy code, because i keep struggeling with all those 'solutions'. it keeps interfering with the execution order or variable accessability.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Handler to schedule work on the main thread using [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)):

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(runnable, delayInMillis);
```

The runnable above is a Runnable instance that does what you want to execute on the main thread.  Keep posting it at each interval, perhaps repeated within the runnable itself to schedule the next iteration.

Comment: This requires a runnable, but when i put it in a runnable i can longer access or modify the mistakes var.

Comment: Move the mistakes var to a class member.

Comment: i edited my example. it more complicated then that. i got constructions with counters within a while.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Timer.html) for this.

```
    Timer mUiUpdateTimer;
    TimerTask uiUpdateTask; 
    int mistakes=0;
    int periodTime=1000;
    private void createTimeHandler()
    {

        mUiUpdateTimer = new Timer();

        final Handler uiUpdateHandler = new Handler();

        final Runnable uiUpdateRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                   // other jobs
                    mistakes++;
            }
        };

        uiUpdateTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //for safe UI handling 
                uiUpdateHandler.post(uiUpdateRunnable);

            }
        };

        mUiUpdateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(uiUpdateTask, 0, periodTime);


    }
```

Comment: That's not helping, it uses a runnable which makes mistakes inaccessable without the final statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add bellow Handler inside your try block

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mistakes++; 
                }
            }

        }, 3000);
```